# Filling in a dataframe from another dataframe using partial string matching

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have two dataframes. Dataframe1 contains climate data for a list of parks. Dataframe 2 contains the Same Parks but there's a letter ("P" or "T") To specify a road within that park. I want to match the climate data to these Parks road designations. For example. In dataframe 1, "Park A" might have 25 cm of precipitation. Dataframe 2 would have "Park A P" and "Park A T". I want dataframe 2 have the value of 25 in both "Park A P" and "Park A T". Any help would be appreciated.

Dataframe1

```
structure(list(ParkName = c("Alafia River State Park", "Amelia Island State Park", 
"Big Talbot Island State Park", "Blue Spring State Park", "Collier-Seminole State Park", 
"Curry Hammock State Park", "Delnor-Wiggins Pass State Park", 
"Dr. Von D. Mizell-Eula Johnson State Park", "Fakahatchee Strand Preserve State Park", 
"Fort George Island Cultural State Park", "Fort Pierce Inlet State Park/Avalon State Park", 
"Fort Zachary Taylor Historic State Park", "Highlands Hammock State Park", 
"Hillsborough River State Park", "Honeymoon Island State Park", 
"John D. MacArthur Beach State Park", "Jonathan Dickinson State Park", 
"Lake Manatee State Park", "Long Key State Park", "Lovers Key State Park", 
"Myakka River State Park", "Oscar Scherer State Park", "Paynes Creek Historic State Park", 
"Pumpkin Hill Creek Preserve State Park", "Savannas Preserve State Park", 
"Seabranch Preserve State Park", "Sebastian Inlet State Park", 
"Terra Ceia Preserve State Park", "Werner-Boyce Salt Springs State Park"
), tmax = c(30.8666666666667, 26.2333333333333, 25.325, 29, 30.3166666666667, 
29.1166666666667, 32.65, 30.7833333333333, 33, 26.3, 27.56, 30.6, 
30.2333333333333, 33, 28.7666666666667, 28.98, 27.9142857142857, 
27.4333333333333, 28.85, 29.4, 30.35, 32.7666666666667, 29.4, 
30.1666666666667, 29.5166666666667, 32.4, 27.2583333333333, 29.7, 
24.4333333333333), tavg = c(25.5, 21.6111111111111, 20.8333333333333, 
23.5, 25.3166666666667, 25.9166666666667, 28, 26.9666666666667, 
28.2, 22.025, 23.3, 28.6, 24.5833333333333, 27.7, 23.8333333333333, 
24.62, 23.0714285714286, 21.5333333333333, 26, 24.32, 24.4166666666667, 
28.0666666666667, 23.5333333333333, 25.9333333333333, 25.1666666666667, 
28.2, 22.875, 24.86, 18.2), tmin = c(20.1333333333333, 17.0222222222222, 
16.3666666666667, 18.02, 20.3166666666667, 22.6833333333333, 
23.35, 23.2, 23.3, 17.75, 19.02, 26.6, 18.8833333333333, 22.45, 
18.8666666666667, 20.28, 18.2285714285714, 15.6333333333333, 
23.1, 19.24, 18.4166666666667, 23.3666666666667, 17.6333333333333, 
21.7333333333333, 20.85, 23.95, 18.4416666666667, 20.04, 11.9333333333333
), precip = c(163.833333333333, 108.333333333333, 116.333333333333, 
104.2, 156, 127.333333333333, 302, 168.166666666667, 259, 111, 
117.8, 154, 131.833333333333, 208.5, 112.333333333333, 152.4, 
94.2857142857143, 179.333333333333, 128.833333333333, 146, 147.666666666667, 
223.666666666667, 137.333333333333, 122.333333333333, 154.166666666667, 
226, 126.5, 137.8, 20.6666666666667), ParkLatitude = c(27.77339935, 
30.52039909, 30.47949982, 28.94799995, 25.97559929, 24.74399948, 
26.28140068, 26.07530022, 26.02120018, 30.42499924, 27.5222, 
24.54649925, 27.4503994, 28.12179947, 28.07509995, 26.82620049, 
27.00860023, 27.47850037, 24.81699944, 26.39119911, 27.22629929, 
27.1807003, 27.61980057, 30.4701004, 27.3166008, 27.13529968, 
27.86020088, 27.5977993, 28.31739998)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("ParkName", "tmax", "tavg", "tmin", 
"precip", "ParkLatitude"), row.names = c(NA, -29L))
```

Dataframe 2

```
    structure(list(newsites = c("Alafia River State Park T", "Blue Spring State Park P", 
"Collier-Seminole State Park T", "Curry Hammock State Park P", 
"Highlands Hammock State Park T", "Jonathan Dickinson State Park P", 
"Jonathan Dickinson State Park T", "John D. MacArthur Beach State Park P", 
"Dr. Von D. Mizell-Eula Johnson State Park P", "Long Key State Park P", 
"Lovers Key State Park T", "Myakka River State Park T", "Myakka River State Park P", 
"Savannas Preserve State Park P", "Seabranch Preserve State Park T", 
"Sebastian Inlet State Park P", "Sebastian Inlet State Park T", 
"Big Talbot Island State Park T", "Big Talbot Island State Park P", 
"Fort George Island Cultural State Park T", "Amelia Island State Park T", 
"Pumpkin Hill Creek Preserve State Park T", "Blue Spring State Park T", 
"Collier-Seminole State Park P", "Delnor-Wiggins Pass State Park P", 
"Fakahatchee Strand Preserve State Park T", "Fort Pierce Inlet State Park/Avalon State Park P", 
"Fort Zachary Taylor Historic State Park P", "Highlands Hammock State Park P", 
"Hillsborough River State Park P", "Honeymoon Island State Park P", 
"Lake Manatee State Park T", "Oscar Scherer State Park P", "Paynes Creek Historic State Park P", 
"Lake Manatee State Park P", "Lovers Key State Park P", "Terra Ceia Preserve State Park T", 
"Werner-Boyce Salt Springs State Park T")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -38L), .Names = "newsites", vars = "newsites", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 20L, 18L, 17L, 1L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 8L, 25L, 19L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 4L, 29L, 30L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 34L, 31L, 9L, 35L, 
    10L, 12L, 11L, 32L, 33L, 21L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 36L, 37L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    newsites = c("Alafia River State Park T", "Amelia Island State Park T", 
    "Big Talbot Island State Park P", "Big Talbot Island State Park T", 
    "Blue Spring State Park P", "Blue Spring State Park T", "Collier-Seminole State Park P", 
    "Collier-Seminole State Park T", "Curry Hammock State Park P", 
    "Delnor-Wiggins Pass State Park P", "Dr. Von D. Mizell-Eula Johnson State Park P", 
    "Fakahatchee Strand Preserve State Park T", "Fort George Island Cultural State Park T", 
    "Fort Pierce Inlet State Park/Avalon State Park P", "Fort Zachary Taylor Historic State Park P", 
    "Highlands Hammock State Park P", "Highlands Hammock State Park T", 
    "Hillsborough River State Park P", "Honeymoon Island State Park P", 
    "John D. MacArthur Beach State Park P", "Jonathan Dickinson State Park P", 
    "Jonathan Dickinson State Park T", "Lake Manatee State Park P", 
    "Lake Manatee State Park T", "Long Key State Park P", "Lovers Key State Park P", 
    "Lovers Key State Park T", "Myakka River State Park P", "Myakka River State Park T", 
    "Oscar Scherer State Park P", "Paynes Creek Historic State Park P", 
    "Pumpkin Hill Creek Preserve State Park T", "Savannas Preserve State Park P", 
    "Seabranch Preserve State Park T", "Sebastian Inlet State Park P", 
    "Sebastian Inlet State Park T", "Terra Ceia Preserve State Park T", 
    "Werner-Boyce Salt Springs State Park T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), vars = "newsites", drop = TRUE, .Names = "newsites"))
```

Comment: The `dput`s for Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 seem to be the same?

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers I've fixed the mistake!

Comment: Almost;-) The first code chunk still contains two `dput`s.

Comment: Ok! Now it's good to go. Sorry about that and thank you!

Comment: So is the only difference always a trailing capital letter? E.g. `"Alafia River State Park T"` vs. `"Alafia River State Park"` Or can there be other differences between the two character strings?

Comment: Yes that's the only difference. Sam gave me a pretty good work around by introducing a new column but if you have any other ideas I'd appreciate it as well!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I have added a `tidyverse` solution below; please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# small data frames for illustration purposes
df1 <- data.frame(park = c('Yellowstone', 'Zion', 'Redwood'), rain = c(1,2,3), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(road = c('Yellowstone P', 'Yellowstone T', 'Zion P', 'Zion T', 'Redwood P', 'Redwood T'), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Make a new column in both data frames which only contains the first 4 characters of the park and road names
df1 <- cbind(df1, shortName = substring(df1$park, 1, 4))
df2 <- cbind(df2, shortName = substring(df2$road, 1, 4))

# Merge df1 and df2 according to the new shortName column we made
df3 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'shortName')

df3
#  shortName        park rain          road
#1      Redw     Redwood    3     Redwood P
#2      Redw     Redwood    3     Redwood T
#3      Yell Yellowstone    1 Yellowstone P
#4      Yell Yellowstone    1 Yellowstone T
#5      Zion        Zion    2        Zion P
#6      Zion        Zion    2        Zion T
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided the only difference between the two `character` strings to be matched is a whitespace-separated single character, here is a `tidyverse` alternative using `dplyr::left_join`

```
library(tidyverse);
df2 %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(ParkName = gsub("\\s[A-Za-z]$", "", newsites)) %>%
    left_join(df1, by = "ParkName") %>%
    select(newsites, precip)
## A tibble: 38 x 2
#   newsites                                    precip
#   <chr>                                        <dbl>
# 1 Alafia River State Park T                    164.
# 2 Blue Spring State Park P                     104.
# 3 Collier-Seminole State Park T                156.
# 4 Curry Hammock State Park P                   127.
# 5 Highlands Hammock State Park T               132.
# 6 Jonathan Dickinson State Park P               94.3
# 7 Jonathan Dickinson State Park T               94.3
# 8 John D. MacArthur Beach State Park P         152.
# 9 Dr. Von D. Mizell-Eula Johnson State Park P  168.
#10 Long Key State Park P                        129.
## ... with 28 more rows
```

Note that `df1` is your "Dataframe 1" and `df2` your "Dataframe 2".

Comment: Certainly a more versatile solution 1+

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers, I have a question about the mutate code you had in your tidyverse pipe. I'm starting to learn about gsub so I know "\\s" means space and then [A-Za-z] means all upper and lowers case letters. However, what does that "$" at the end mean? thanks again!

Comment: @LeoOhyama `"$"` is the end-of-string anchor; for example, `"T$"` would match strings where the *last* character is a `"T"`.